# State-space representation of a nonlinear MIMO system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system

**Question:** Obtain a state-space representation of nonlinear multiple-input multiple-output (MIMO) system:

$$\dddot{y}_1 + 2\dot{y_1} + 3y_2 + 2 = u_1 y_2 \tag{1}$$
$$\ddot{y}_2 - 2 \dot{y}_2 + \dot{y}_1^3 + y_2 + y_1 = (u_2 - u_3)y_1 \tag{2}$$

I find it difficult solving the above equations. I have the following queries:

1. What do I do with $(dy_1/dt)^3$? How do I represent it in state space model?
2. Are $u_1, u_2$ and $u_3$ control inputs or just constants (coefficients of $y_1$ and $y_2$)?
3. Does the constant $2$ in equation come in $\mathbf B$ (i.e., $\mathbf A x + \mathbf B u)$?
4. Do I have to convert these equations into linear equations?

Comment: (1) Since you will set a new variable $v=y_1'$, that term becomes $v^3$ (2) Impossible to tell with further context.  (3) I don't know what you're asking (4) No, there is no way to do so.

Comment: @Paul 1. Yeah, I've taken v=y1' but then, how do I represent it in state-space(Matrix form i.e f(x,u))
3. What do I do with the number '2'(scalar quantity) in equation 1. In which matrix does it come in State-space rep?

Answer (score 3):

Let $y_3=y_1'$, $y_4=y_2'$, $y_5=y_3'$.  Then the state space equations look like

$$y_1'=y_3$$
$$y_2'=y_4$$
$$y_3'=y_5$$
$$y_4'-2y_4+y_3^3+y_2+y_1=(u_2-u_3)y_1$$
$$y_5'+2y_3+3y_2+2=u_1y_2$$

Comment: Shouldn't the 3rd equation be y3''?

Comment: No, if $y_1'=y_3$, then $y_1''=y'_3$

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But then,  in the question it is y1''' so it should be y3'' right?

Comment: Oh! I missed the third derivative.  So will need a fifth variable.  I will edit accordingly.

Comment: This is where I got stuck. Now, how do I represent these equations in state-space representation(Ax+Bu). 
Or since it is a non-linear system they cannot be represented in Ax+Bu form?

Comment: Right, there's no way to make the non-linearity go away.  I don't think a state space representation is necessarily linear however.

Comment: The most general state space form of a nonlinear differential equation would be $\dot{x}=f(t,x,u)$, where $x$ is the entire state, in this case containing $y_1$ till $y_5$.

Comment: well then can I represent those equations in matrix form?

Comment: No, only linear equations can be represented in matrix form.